# Get free option quotes

Tags: united-states, canada, options, google-finance

Is there a google or yahoo api that provides option quotes similar to the below for stock quotes?
http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=3d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=SPY

I am looking to get quotes on options traded on major north american exchanges (CBOE, Bourse de Montreal)

I am not looking for real time, 15 min delay is perfectly fine, but I am looking for free quotes.

Answer (score 1):

A number of sites provide delayed option chains online.

[Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=AAPL%20Options) is one example:

[image]

I linked to Apple's chain, but to get one yourself, put the ticker you want in the search box, then click the "options" link in the sidebar that I called out in the image.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, since you asked for Montreal, you can get the quotes directly.

http://www.m-x.ca/nego_cotes_en.php